# Unity prevent players from colliding with each other

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm building a 2D multiplayer game with Unity and Photon and I'm currently facing a problem where my players are colliding with each other and I don't want this behavior to happen...

I'm using the Unity [InputSytem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/manual/QuickStartGuide.html)

**This is my player prefab options:**

[image]

**And that's my PlayerController script:**

```
void OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info){
        if(stream.isWriting){
            stream.SendNext(transform.position);
            stream.SendNext(localPlayerName.text);
        } else{
            targetPosition = (Vector3)stream.ReceiveNext();
            remotePlayerName.SetText((string)stream.ReceiveNext());
        }
    }

private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(PhotonView.isMine){
            if(movementInput != Vector2.zero){
                int count = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().Cast(
                    movementInput,
                    movementFilter,
                    castCollisions,
                    moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime + collisionOffset
                );

                if(count == 0){
                    transform.position += (Vector3)movementInput * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;                
                }
            }
        } else {
            moveOtherPlayer();
        }
    }

private void moveOtherPlayer() {
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, 0.25f);
    }

void OnMove(InputValue movementValue){
        this.movementInput = movementValue.Get<Vector2>();
    }
```

how can I avoid the collision between the 2 player instances ?

Comment: Check out [Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html)

Comment: @hijinxbassist so I should create a new Layer for every player ?

Comment: No, put them all on the same layer, and set that layer not to collide with itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day!

You could try turning off object collisions in the layer collision matrix. You can find the matrix in: Edit > Project Settings and in the Physics tab.
How it works is:

1. You assign your GameObjects (your players) to a layer in the top-right.
2. Go the the matrix and where the layer columns and rows meet, there will be a tickbox.
3. If you turn off that tickbox, then it means that GameObjects with those layers will ignore collisions with eachother. Triggers will also ignore eachother.

I hope this helps and good luck in your project!

Comment: Read more about the layer collision matrix here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html

Comment: thank you for your answer, does this work with rigidbody.Cast() ?